# jquery ui greedy not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

So what i'm trying to do is to place an item( the diamond shaped item ) in the droppable and that item creates 2 sub-droppables in wich you place items, but the thing is i can't seem to get the "greedy" function to work with the generated droppables. Currently i'm only testing it on the second item - left side when generated. 
my [My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L22d4x2x/5/) . 

This is the main dropzone.

```
            $(".objects").droppable({
            accept: "#block",
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                $(".test").append('Dropped!');
            }});
```

This is the sub-dropzone. On drop there should appear Dropped123! in the bottom code paragraph.

```
          $(".true").droppable({
                greedy:true,
                accept: "#block",
                drop : function (ev, ui) {
                    $(".test").append('Dropped123!');


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to bind droppable before you actually have the elements, I have changed your fiddle so now you bind the event to the actual element:
http://jsfiddle.net/L22d4x2x/7/

```
                var divTrue = $('<div class="true n_block'+ cloneCount1 +'"></div>');
                $(".n_block"+ cloneCount1 ).append(divTrue); 
                divTrue.droppable({
                    greedy:true,
                    accept: "#block",
                    drop : function (ev, ui) {debugger;
                        $(".test").append('Dropped123!');

                    }
                });
```

Comment: hm.. it kind of makes sence now. Thank you very much for the anwser.

Comment: would you know by any chance how to append new items to the  sub-drop zone?

Comment: what do you mean by sub-drop zone?

Comment: if it's at any help i'm trying to make a programming flowchart application.. and that would be like the "If- statement block"

Comment: aight' managed to get something working : http://jsfiddle.net/L22d4x2x/25/ this is what i was thinking about, but it's still buggy as hell :/